# Questions tagged as [optimization] instead of [mathematical-optimization]

Tags: discussion

It seems to me that there are a number of questions dealing with mathematical optimization that are being given the [optimization] tag. Recent examples:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23490169/optimization-algorithm-in-multidimensional-variables

[Find Maximum sum in a path in a 2D matrix with positive integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23483753/find-maximum-sum-in-a-path-in-a-2d-matrix-with-positive-integers)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482935/optimizing-parameters-given-underlying-garch1-1-model-in-r

Based on my understanding, the [optimization] tag is really all about speeding up/streamlining code, while the [mathematical-optimization] tag is about math programming (e.g. linear or nonlinear optimization).

A canonical example of mathematical optimization is linear programming. Of the 325 questions tagged with [linear-programming], 48 are also tagged with [optimization] while 58 are tagged with [mathematical-optimization]. My unscientific conclusion from this is that nearly half of all questions that should be tagged as [mathematical-optimization] are instead being given the [optimization] tag.

Do others agree these sorts of questions are being mis-tagged as [optimization]? If so, I would love to spearhead a cleanup convert them to [mathematical-optimization].

Comment: Any progress in the subject since? The number of questions that use [optimization] for mathematical questions are increasing and we can't avoid users to do so, since the about page of [optimization] even kind of promotes using the tag for "numerical-optimization". I'm for using [mathematical-optimization] myself, but I think it's more important to make a decision. Let's separate them or make them synonyms.

Comment: @saastn I think there's great value in them being separated (the types of people who do these two types of things are often very different). It would just be a big cleanup project!